# Bubble Sort Using Slides instead of swaps

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

currently I'm being asked to design four sorting algorithms (insertion, shell, selection, and bubble) and I have 3 of the 4 working perfectly; the only one that isn't functioning correctly is the Bubble Sort. Now, I'm well aware of how the normal bubble sort works with using a temp var to swap the two indexes, but the tricky part about this is that it needs to use the array index[0] as a temp instead of a normal temp, which is used in swapping, and slide the lower array variables down to the front of the list and at the end of the pass assign the last index to the temp which is the greatest value.

I've been playing around with this for a while and even tried to look up references but sadly I cannot find anything. I'm hoping that someone else has done this prior and can offer some helpful tips. This is sort of a last resort as I've been modifying and running through the passes with pen and paper to try and find my fatal error. Anyways, my code is as follows...

```
void BubbleSort(int TheArray[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        TheArray[0] = TheArray[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < size; j++)
        {
            if (TheArray[j] > TheArray[0])
                TheArray[0] = TheArray[j];
            else
            {
                TheArray[j - 1] = TheArray[j];
            }
        }
        TheArray[size- 1] = TheArray[0];
    }
}
```

Thanks for any feedback whatsoever; it's much appreciated.

Comment: It might pay to provide the exact wording of what you've been asked to do, in case you misinterpreted it.  From what I see here, the first thing you do is overwrite the value of `TheArray[0]`, which can't be a good thing.

Comment: You could use an [XOR-Swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

Comment: If the stated goal is to shift a sub-array downwards (what you call slide), then it's not a bubble sort, but variation of insertion sort that could be called deletion sort. You still need a temp variable to hold the first value before it gets overwritten when the sub-array is shifted down, then you put that value at the now vacant spot left by the shift. if TheArray[0] is not considered as part of the data, then it could be used as a temp variable.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem statement, I think you're looking for something along these lines :

```
void BubbleSort(int theArray[], int size)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        theArray[0] = theArray[1];
        for (int j = 1; j <= size + 1 - i; j++)
        {
            if (theArray[j] > theArray[0])
            {
                theArray[j-1] = theArray[0];
                theArray[0] = theArray[j];
            }
            else
            {
                theArray[j - 1] = theArray[j];
            }
        }
        theArray[size-i+1] = theArray[0];
    }
}
```

The piece that you're code was missing, I think, was that once you find a new maximum, you have to put it back in the array before placing the new maximum in theArray[0] storage location (see theArray[j-1] = theArray[0] after the compare).  Additionally, the inner loop wants to run one less each time since the last element will be the current max value so you don't want to revisit those array elements.  (See for(int j = 1 ; j <= size + 1 - i ; j++))

For completeness, here's the main driver I used to (lightly) test this :

```
int main()
{
    int theArray[] = { 0, 5, 7, 3, 2, 8, 4, 6 };
    int size = 7;

    BubbleSort(theArray, size);
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
        cout << theArray[i] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```